# htaccess doesn't work properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I trying to prevent the images showing directly in the url bar. for that i have my htaccess file with the below code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://manga.animworld.net [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

This works fine in localhost but when i upload it to my server it just doesn't work.

I did put some garbage in htaccess file to see if it working at all, it did work and i got server error on the main domain but i didn't get anything on the direct image url.

my httpd.conf file also has the below code:

```
<Directory "/">
Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks IncludesNOEXEC Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Did you change `sub.mysite.com` to actual domain name?

Comment: @anubhava yes i did change it to `manga.animworld.net` which is my domain.